# How to create a dictionary using regular expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some heading like that :

> From: author@example.com
>
> User-Agent: Thunderbird 1.5.0.9 (X11/20061227)
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> To: editor@example.com

and I have to make a dictionary . I think that I have to use re.match function but I don't know how to connect it with dictionary. I am beginer in Python and it's hard for me .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is all one string, you could do something like

```
import re

s="""
From: author@example.com

User-Agent: Thunderbird 1.5.0.9 (X11/20061227)

MIME-Version: 1.0

To: editor@example.com
"""

d = dict(re.findall(r'^\s*([^:]+): (.+?)\s*$', s, flags=re.M))

print(d)

{'From': 'author@example.com', 
 'User-Agent': 'Thunderbird 1.5.0.9 (X11/20061227)', 
 'MIME-Version': '1.0', 
 'To': 'editor@example.com'}
```

We're using `re.M`, which is multiline mode, so `^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end.

Breaking the regex into pieces:

```
^\s*        Zero or more spaces at the beginning of a line
([^:]+):    Keep all of characters that aren't : until we get to a :
(.+?)       Take one or more characters, as few as possible
\s*$        Zero or more spaces at the end of the line
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to separate field names from values, you could use a regular expression based on the presence of the colon. For instance:

```
import re

header = """From: author@example.com
User-Agent: Thunderbird 1.5.0.9 (X11/20061227)
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: editor@example.com"""

pattern = re.compile(r"^([^:]+):\s+(.+)$")

fields = []
for line in header.split("\n"):
    fields.append(pattern.match(line).groups())

d = dict(fields)
```

If you don't know regular expressions very well, you might try first by simply using the '''split()''' method of strings. Just try: `"From: author@example.com".split(":")` in your Python console.

Comment: Thank you , this is what I ment ;)